# FireFTP with Hotspot Shield

Tags: networking, proxy, ftp, file-transfer, hotspot-shield

I can use the FireFTP fine until I turn the Hotspot Shield on, then I cannot connect anymore.

I think I need to configure the proxy settings in FireFTP but what I have tried so far did not work.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: view the current proxy server after connecting hss and then enter it in settings menu of fireFTP and apply changes.

Comment: So, I determined my external IP address via http://www.whatismyip.com/ I entered that address into FireFTP settings as the proxy host address and I set the proxy port number as 21 (is this correct?) and proxy type 'Direct'. I also set the connection to use the passive mode with port 21. Does this sound right? I still cannot connect.

Comment: You don't normally have to set a proxy when you use a VPN. The proxy's  address would not be your own IP address anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that your VPN service doesn't allow FTP traffic at all.

Comment: You may be right, but I don't know. I started reading more closely and only the paid version of Hotspot Shield mentions FTP. I am using the free version. Maybe someone can clarify if the free version supports FTP. I haven't been able to find it.

Comment: I tried to look on the Web and couldn't find any mention of that. Maybe someone will see this thread and tell you, but I think it's safe to assume it doesn't allow FTP traffic through.